# GridView Databinding - timeout

Tags: c#, .net, timeout

I do have the ASP.NET page, that calls stored procedure through SqlDataSource on Page_Load and Binds GridView. On PageLoad I am doing something like this:

```
string connectionString = BLTutela.BLclsDatabaseConfigurations.GetDefaultConnectionString();
dataSource.ConnectionString = connectionString;
dataSource.SelectParameters["ReportFromDate"].DefaultValue = reportFromDateValue.Date.ToString();
...            
GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

dataSource is SqlDataSource and calls StoredProcedure.
The code is working, but it is just a first version, because there could be the following problems (I think that these problems could happen, because it is Report page that generates very long reports):

1) Stored Procedure can run too long -> SessionTimeout can happen and also user doesn't see any response from system for a very long time

2) Even if stored procedure has been finished, loading data into gridview could be a very long process too. This could result in another Session Timeout.

I need a sollution that 
1) doesn't show session timeouts for long server pocess (stored procedure) 
2) no timeout for showing data in gridview,
3) shows progress bar while data are loading.

I have never worked with Threads or AsyncCalls, so I wanted to do some investigation first.

For now I have found the following link: 
http://madskristensen.net/post/Asynchronous-GridView-in-5-simple-steps.aspx
and I wonder if this will work for my case and what problems I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

In order to resolve your problem you can define `Timeout on your string connection`

Adjust `Connect Timeout` property

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=;Connect Timeout=200" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

You can set timeout value in SqlDataSource's Selecting event:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender,
SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Command.CommandTimeout = 200;
}
```

Comment: This solves only stored procedure timeout, how about GridView timeout? And how about progress bar? (otherwise, system would be unresponsive for too long).

Comment: For your grid view you manage session timeout : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx

Comment: progress bar?  you must use ajax control for example ProgressBar ; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10452/Create-Simple-ASP-NET-Progress-Bar-Control

Comment: As I have read session timeout is for all application, I need to change session timeout only for this one particular task.

Comment: And given ProgressBar doesn't show how to use it with GridView in my case - I do not have any Ajax there yet, how do I now huw many rows are loaded and other staff like this?

Comment: ProgressBar : http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2008/03/14/free-progress-bar-for-asp-net.aspx

Comment: For above comments I do understand that I can use Server.ScriptTimeout or e.Command.CommandTime for Server timeout. But I do not see any sollution for data loadiwng into GridView SessionTimeout. And given sollutions above for progress bar are just progressbar images... If I do have GridView, how to combine GridView with progressbar, so progressbar indicates how many rows have been loaded / left?

Comment: GridView don't have Timeout property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_properties(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I'am sorry i come back in the night

Comment: If Data are loading too long into GridView, then it would result in browser timeout. Is not it? So I guess I need some Thread or Async process to bind data into gridview + showing progress bar.

Comment: I have just found in web that there is an UpdateProgress control. Would it work if I add e.Command.CommandTimeout = 200; 
Then I create UpdatePanel, put my GridView into it and then create UpdateProgress control. UpdateProgress would show progress bar. Would not be there any Session timeouts?